# При сборке приложения на react native выходит ошибка Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration

Tags: react-native

Вот что показывает консоль:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApkCopy'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1.
     Required by:
         project :app
         project :app > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.55.4
      > Skipped due to earlier error
   > Could not resolve javax.inject:javax.inject:1.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.55.4
      > Skipped due to earlier error
   > Could not resolve com.facebook.fbui.textlayoutbuilder:textlayoutbuilder:1.0                                                               .0.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.55.4
      > Skipped due to earlier error
   > Could not resolve com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.3.0.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.55.4
      > Skipped due to earlier error
   > Could not resolve com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline-okhttp3:1.3.0.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.55.4
      > Skipped due to earlier error
   > Could not resolve com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.1.0.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.55.4
      > Skipped due to earlier error
   > Could not resolve com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.0.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.55.4
      > Skipped due to earlier error
   > Could not resolve com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.55.4
      > Skipped due to earlier error
   > Could not resolve com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.6.0.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.55.4
      > Skipped due to earlier error
   > Could not resolve com.squareup.okio:okio:1.13.0.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.55.4
      > Skipped due to earlier error
   > Could not resolve org.webkit:android-jsc:r174650.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.55.4
      > Skipped due to earlier error

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug                                                                option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4m 24s
```

Как исправить ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте в ваш файл `build.gradle`(тот что в корне каталога android)  `maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }`

Выглядеть должно вот так:

```
allprojects {
  repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com'
    }
    maven {
        // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
        url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: спасибо огромное! BUILD SUCCESSFUL